# RPi 4: Crackling audio over HDMI cable (using Samsung TV)

Tags: audio, pi-4

I recently got an RPi 4 but unless I mute my TV there is this persistent crackling sound (every few seconds.) I tried to use the headphone jack and it works but it doesn't stop the crackling sound from the TV. Any suggestions on how to stop this?

Comment: Possible ground / interference issue?  Does it change if you unplug everything bar from power?  Does it change if you swap resolution or task? Do you have another cable or you could try?  Make sure you have slack in the cable so it's not straining the connectors.  Possibly a clean with IPA may help?

Comment: I'm a very new user so I do not understand what you mean by most questions. I doubt that cleaning would help as it is entirely new. I did try switching to another HDMI port but that didn't make any difference. One thing I wonder might be involved is that the TV has 3 ports:  HDMI2/DVI is connected to a Mac Mini that I use it to play videos via Kodi,  RPi 4 uses HDMI1.

Comment: It seems that there is no audible crackling when I use Kodi to play videos. But still happens when I am not using apps with audible.